# Установки среды с Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, база-данных

Скачивал Delphi 7. После установки при открытии возникает ошибка

> `Unable to rename 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Bin\delphi32.$$$' to 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Bin\delphi32.dro'.`

Какие среды содержат Delphi и подойдут для разработки интерактивного визуализатора баз данных? Если можно, то приведите ссылки для скачивания этих сред.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delphi это и есть среда, она нигде больше не содержится. Попробуйте выкинуть Delphi 7 и взять версию поновее. Хотя бы 2010.
2. Учитывая, что Delphi вы, кажется, приобретать не собираетесь, можете попробовать еще Lazarus.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде чем задать вопрос, можно самому попробовать решить проблему или найти ответ в гугле или на данном ресурсе. Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/132271/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-delphi) есть ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решается двумя путями:

1. Запустить программу от имени администратора
2. Надо изменить разрешения на доступ к папке с Delphi. В свойствах папки надо разрешить смотреть и изменять файлы всем подряд.